# Error message "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable." after editing a file

Tags: themes, editor

After trying to edit/update a file in the theme editor (file file has write permissions of 666), I get an error message saying "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.
Please try again later. "  The file never gets updated because the server won't process the change I made to the file.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is the PHP user the owner of the file?

Comment: yes, i have access to the backend of the site but i don't have access to the actual server.  only thing i can do is download/upload files (and delete files) via ftp and access the backend.  i found a temporary workaround which is to download the files that i needed to edit, edit them on my computer in my text editor, save the file, then upload it to the server.  can't edit it in wordpress so i edited the file on my computer.

Comment: What I meant: The _file owner_ on the server may be another one. Ownership on the file system is something completely different than the ability to see the backend. There are some [notes on the Codex about this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions).